# how the keys event registred , when press the keys inside the textarea on ( python / tkinter )

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming and I choice python my first language.  I try to solve that problem alone but I can't. I want  a solution how the key-event get  registered for I could count how much key press event done inside the textarea.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjKDx.png)

```
from Tkinter import *


    def keyup(u):
        print 'up', u.char

    def keydown(d):
        print 'down', d.char


    root = Tk()
    T = Text(root, height=2, width=300 )
    T.pack()
    frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
    frame.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
    frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
    frame.pack()
    frame.focus_set()



    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your screen capture is a bit small, it is difficult to see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I post again the screen capture , the probleme is when I type any key it display the event of  up , down  but when the cursor is focused on the text area i couldn't see the event I want solution for that

Comment: Did you try binding your key to the text area and not the frame?

Comment: thank you for the solution I try and am getting familiar with the bind now